# Show that for any events $A$ and $B$, $P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability

It is clear to me why $P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$ by picturing a Venn diagram, but I'm not sure how to show this is true for any event $A \text{ and } B$.

Answer (score 2):

The law of total probability states that for any partition (disjoint sets whose union is the whole space) $\{E_i\}$ of a probability space,

$$P(A)=\sum_i P(A\cap E_i).$$

Note that $\{B, B^c\}$ is a partition (they are disjoint and the union is the entire space).

Thus

$$P(A)=P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c),$$

and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

A first (short) answer is that it can be deduced from the fact that if $E, F$ are disjoint events then $\mathbb{P}(E\cup F)=\mathbb{P}(E)+\mathbb{P}(F)$. Applying this property to events $A\cap B^C$ and $A\cap B$ gives us:

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}((A\cap B^C) \cup (A\cap B)) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B^C)+\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$$

from which the identity you wished to prove can be deduced.

A second (longer) answer is that since this is one of the most fundamental properties that a probability measure satisfies, then if one wants to write a rigorous proof then one needs to know which properties a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ satisfies by definition to use when proving the property. One definition of a probability space (there are other equivalent ones) is the one that follows:

A probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ consists of a set $\Omega$, a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ $\mathcal{F}$ and a function $\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{F}\to[0,1]$ satisfying:

1. $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$.
2. If $A, B\in\mathcal{F}$ satisfy $A\subseteq B$, then $\mathbb{P}(A)\leq \mathbb{P}(B)$.
3. If $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets, then $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(A_n)$.

Then using these axioms, one can show that $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0$, and then $\mathbb{P}(E\cup F) = \mathbb{P}(E) + \mathbb{P}(F)$ for disjoint sets $E, F\in\mathcal{F}$. Once one has deduced this property, the proof can be finished by proceeding like the first (shorter) answer to the question.

To prove the first two properties, one can do so as follows:

1. $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = \mathbb{P}(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\emptyset) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset)\in [0,1]$ implies $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)$ cannot be strictly positive since in such case the sum would be infinite, so it must be equal to $0$.
2. Then if $E, F\in\mathcal{F}$ are disjoint sets we have for $A_1=E, A_2=F, A_n=\emptyset$ for all $n\geq 3$:
   $$\mathbb{P}(E\cup F) = \mathbb{P}(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(A_n) = \mathbb{P}(E) + \mathbb{P}(F)$$
   where we use that $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0$ for the last equalty.